# Is there a discussion group about google search?

Tags: search-engines, google-search

I figured that google search efficiency is getting worse over the years(and yes I can't find anything regarding this question with google search), either my searching skill is deteriorating or SEOs are doing their job well. So anyway is there a discussion group about search engineering from a googler's perspective(instead of content owner)?

Comment: You may consider contacting [Matt Cutts](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/).

Comment: @ChrisF Daniel-beck should web services be considered software in a border term? I think it's a bit narrow limiting software to "installed software" from today's point of view

Comment: @vasa1 I'm sure the guys at Google are working hard wresting with the massive data of WWW. However the chaotic nature of internet makes it inherently difficult to find data that fits your needs... A whole range of different techniques should be practiced to find the precise answer/range of possible solutions. I'm looking for this kind of forum, where questions can be asked and techniques can be discussed.

Answer (score 0):

Are the regular Google Search forums for end users not what you are looking for e.g. http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!categories/websearch ?

These are not for SEO experts.

Comment: This is a product forum, I see their topics are about the products, not about search techniques per se.